# KVM and USB devices attachments

Tags: kvm

I have not so nice problem with USB devices connection to my VM machine. My situation. I'm using libvirt for my machines management. I have two identical USB network adapters. I want to connect one of these nics to my VM with attach command. So in my situation Product and Vendor ids will not help as they are the same of the both usb devices and its not enough to specify only these things. Ok, so there is another thing when I can use address clause (in the xml) to specify bus number and device number. But there goes another problem - device number gets incremented after each usb device reconnection and possibly will change after host reboot. So what are my options then? Was not able to find out any solution on the internet:(

Comment: Try `lsusb -t`, and you can see which ports your devices are connected to. There are symlinks in `/sys` that reflect this. `qemu-kvm -device usb-host,?` should show you which properties you can use; if necesary, convert from where `/sys` links you.

Comment: But I'm using virsh for my devices attachments not quemu-kvm. And I want my device to be auto attached when the host is rebooted and when my VM is autostarted. As for now my solution was to write a script which runs on device attachment with the help of udev, figures out device number, creates xml config for device attachment and attaches this device to VM. But I thought that maybe there is more elegant solution for this...

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information (comments may not be permanent).